# Break recursion the right way

Tags: python

Trying to solve Leetcode problem 55. Jump Game; i decided to break recursion with a try except block and custom Exception, do you see a more clever way of doing it ? I feel like I am doing the wrong way to break recursion ...

```
class Solution(object):
    def canJump(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        reachable = [False]*len(nums)
        class BreackRecursion(Exception):
            pass
        def jump(nums,pos):
            max_step = nums[pos]
            reachable[pos]=True
            if reachable[-1]==True:
                raise BreackRecursion
            for step in range(1,max_step+1):
                print(pos,step,max_step,list(range(1,max_step+1)),reachable)
                try:
                    reachable[pos+step]=True
                    jump(nums,pos+step)
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                
        try:       
            jump(nums,0)
        except BreackRecursion:
            return True
        return False



S= Solution()
inputs =[[2,3,1,1,4],[3,2,1,0,4]]
for input in inputs:
    print("input:",input)
    s = S.canJump(input)
    print(s)
```

Comment: jump is the recursive function here, i embeded it to keep an external container (the list named "reachable")

Comment: will it break? inside the function you have a try that will capture an exception and do nothing.

Comment: When you find yourself using exceptions as "goto", you're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal

```
class SolutionNew:
    def canJump(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        def jump(nums, pos):
            max_step = nums[pos]

            # 1 -- you are just breaking when reaching last position
            if pos == len(nums) - 1:
                # 2 -- just use a flag to end your recursion
                return False

            for step in range(1, max_step + 1):
                print(pos, step, max_step, list(range(1, max_step + 1)))

                # 3 -- an "if" statement may be more elegant here
                next_pos = pos + step
                if next_pos < len(nums):
                    # 4 -- propagate your "False" flag
                    if not jump(nums, next_pos):
                        return False

            # 5 -- when normal ending, you just flag that a new loop can be performed
            return True

        # 6 -- ensure the logic is ok
        return not jump(nums, 0)
```

1. Setting `reachable[pos]` to `True` and then checking for last value of `reachable` is just like looking if `pos == len(reachable)-1` (or `len(nums)-1` since `len(reachable) == len(nums)`.
2. Instead of raising an `Exception`, you could just set a flag. Then you should just take care of propagating that flag, through *#4* (you want to stop immediately if `False` flag is returned) and *#5* (normal ending -> proceed with next iteration).
3. Instead of `try ... except` you can just see if `next_pos` fits in. Notice also that `reachable[pos + step] = True` before calling `jump(nums, pos + step)` was reduntant, since the `jump` call sets it to True almost immediately. At this point, indeed, you do not even need `reachable` anymore.
4. See *#2*.
5. See *#2*.
6. Just to adjust the logic, in order to return `True` when recursion stops (i.e. `BreackRecursion` was raised).

Here some test code:

```
S = Solution()
S_new = SolutionNew()
inputs = [
    [2, 3, 1, 1, 4],
    [3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
    [5, 1, 6, 10, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2],
    [123, 321, 25, 87, 6],
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
]
for input in inputs:
    print("input:", input)
    s = S.canJump(input)
    s_new = S_new.canJump(input)
    assert s == s_new, 'Solutions are different!'
    print(s_new)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If i understand well there is a propagation of the flag (i can turn False to True and erase the not keyword to simplify i suppose) so it takes a little more time since it doesn't stop immediately ?

Comment: Actually, testing the solution on many many inputs, it seems to me that the proposed solution is 2 to 3 times faster. Consider that `Exception`s are back propagated too, you just don't see it, while here you are making it explicit. Anyway, if you are concerned about performance, you should rethink your `for step in range(...)` loop, since you are calling several times your `jump` function with the same arguments (and since it is recursive, your complexity would explode).

Comment: i took that problem from leetcode, do you think it is a better way to put a self argument in jump function (i can see this practice in most solutions from other contestnts); if yes why ? :)

Comment: Obviously there are infinite ways to achieve a result, and the best use of self arguments strongly depends on use case. I believe that for your class, you may avoid it since it is not stricly necessary (and you may end up with a mess if you lack of attention in recursion). On the other hand, it might simplify your coding. If you are interested, I think you may ask a new question with few approaches, asking for best one :)